# How to append in html by ajax as looping order?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I started learning callback function and I do append html after callback ! When I use ajax callback function in `for loop`,it's doesn't append like looping order ! It is randomly append in body `eg.1,4,2,3` . I want to append as looping order (1,2,3,4),but without waiting one ajax to complete ?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var AJAX = {
    call : function(id,callback) {
      $.ajax({
        url : "sample.php",
        data : {id:id},
        success : callback
      })
    }
  };
  for(var i =1;i < 5;i++) {
  AJAX.call(i,function(html){
    $("body").append(html);
  });
  }
</script></body></html>
```

## Sample.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  echo "<h".$_GET['id'].">This is heading ".$_GET['id'];
}
```

```
This is heading 1
This is heading 4
This is heading 2
This is heading 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider inserting empty containers that will be populated with the correct content upon callback?

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('body').append('<div id="div' + i + '"></div>');
  (function(){
    var x = $('#div' + i);
      AJAX.call(i,function(html){
        x.append(html);
      });
  })();
}
```

Comment: by the way i like your idea of appending a div .. but the problem is that it wont append until one loop ends

Comment: If `AJAX.call` is an asynchronous function with a callback, it should return immediately so the loop will keep going without waiting for the callback to complete.

Comment: I have edited the answer to invoke the AJAX call in a closure, so in every iteration of the loop the newly appended `<div>` is assigned to a variable in an internal scope, and then passed to the AJAX callback function. Please see https://codepen.io/hydrospell/pen/JyMWxO/

Comment: Is a `$` typo in `$(x).append(html);` ? I think no need to use that

Comment: You're right, it's unnecessary as x is already a jQuery element object. Edited!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to give every `html` that you get from server an order.And apped it to `body` by the given orders.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
var temp = i;

(function(temp) { // use closure to save i
    AJAX.call(i,
    function(html) {
        var $html = $(html).data('order', temp),
        $children = $('body').children();

        if ($children.length === 0) { // the body is empty yet
            $('body').append($html);
        } else { // some requests has return from server, and body is not empty now
            $children.each(function(index) {
                var order = parseInt($(this).data('order'), 10);

                if (index === $children.length - 1) { // last children
                    // insert before or after by order
                    temp > order ? $(this).after($html) : $(this).before($html);
                } else {
                    var nextChildOrder = parseInt($children.eq(index + 1), 10);
                    if (temp < order) { // insert before
                        $(this).before($html);
                    } else if (temp > order && temp < nextChildOrder) { // insert after
                        $(this).after($html);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(temp);
}
```

Comment: Your code give me this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement`

Comment: @DavidJorHpan Now I edit my answer, and test it on my own server. I think this time it will work.

Comment: It's not working !! Also I don't want to change my coding design `AJAX.call`

Comment: @DavidJorHpan Use your code design this time.But have to add a closure to save variable `i`.Replace your for loop with my code and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You could add in one array and after the ajax calls print it normally.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var order = new Array();

function add2arrayOrder(i,html)
{
    order[i]=html;
    //alert(i);
}

var AJAX = {
    call : function(id,callback) {
      $.ajax({
        url : "sample.php",
        data : {id:id},
        success : function(html) 
                  {
                    add2arrayOrder(id,html);
                  }
      })
    }
  };

  // make Ajax calls
  for(i =1;i < 5;i++) 
  {
      AJAX.call(i,function(html)
      {
            add2arrayOrder(i,html);
            //alert(order[i]);
      });
  }

// wait a little and print
setTimeout(function(){
  for(i=1;i < 5;i++) 
  {
    $("body").append(order[i]);
  }  
},500);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```